# Can I examine exit code within ternary operator?

Tags: bash, exit-code, ternary

I am trying to print a string depending on the exit code of a `test` built-in and ternary operator. I am successful to:

```
b=5
echo $(( b==5 ? good : bad ))   # good is printed
```

good is printed as expected, but if I do:

```
echo $(( test $b -eq 50 ? 123 : 321 ))
test 5 -eq 50 ? 123 : 321 : syntax error in expression (error token is "5 -eq 50 ? 123 : 321 ")
echo $(( $(test $b -eq 5)==0 ? 123 : 321 ))
 ==0 ? 123 : 321 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "==0 ? 123 : 321 ")
```

Let's say I want to report file existence, none of the following didn't work as well:

```
echo $(( $((test -e file))==0 ? 123 : 321 ))
test -e file: syntax error in expression (error token is "file")
echo $(( ((test -e file))==0 ? 123 : 321 ))
((test -e file))==0 ? 123 : 321 : missing `)' (error token is "file))==0 ? 123 : 321 ")
echo $(( (test -e file)==0 ? 123 : 321 ))
(test -e file)==0 ? 123 : 321 : missing `)' (error token is "file)==0 ? 123 : 321 ")
echo $(( "test -e file" ? 123 : 321 ))
"test -e file" ? 123 : 321 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is ""test -e file" ? 123 : 321 ")
```

Is it any possible construct in ternary operator that can examine an exit code?

Comment: Under [tag:bash]: `b=5;echo $(( b==5 ? good : bad ))   # good is printed` ?? I can't reproduce this!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(( arithmetic context ))` expects an arithmetic expression; obviously random strings (which apparently you hope to have executed as commands) are not arithmetic expressions, so that's a syntax error.

Probably try

```sh
echo $(( $(test "$b" -eq 50; echo $?) ? 123 : 321 ))
```

etc; but obviously, a much less convoluted and more idiomatic way to say this is

```sh
test "$b" -eq 50 && echo 123 || echo 321
```

You can't refactor the `echo` out; in this isolated example, that's just a minor inconvenience. If you really need to avoid repeating more complex code, replace `echo` with a function which encapsulates whatever it is that you don't want to repeat.

A `$(command substitution)` replaces the command with whatever it prints to standard output. If you want to examine its exit code, you need it to print that (and nothing else) to standard output, or use a different construction.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, use an array index.

Typical construct:

```sh
b=5
str=(bad good)
echo "${str[b==5]}"
```

This uses the output of the arithmetic comparison as an array index.

Answer (score 1):

## Strings as messages

You could build a message array as:

```
MSGS=('Good result' 'Wrong result' [123]='Existing entry' [321]='Broken link')
```

Then you will need some constants:

```
good=0 bad=1 exist=123 notexist=321
```

Then use integer as:

```
b=5 file=/tmp
printf "B: %s %s, Entry: '%s' %s\n"   "$b" "${MSGS[ b==5 ? good : bad ]}" \
       "$file" "${MSGS[ $(test -e "$file";echo $?) ? notexist : exist ]}"
B: 5 Good result, Entry: '/tmp' Existing entry
```

Or

```
b=12 file=/tnt
printf "B: %s %s, Entry: '%s' %s\n"   "$b" "${MSGS[ b==5 ? good : bad ]}" \
       "$file" "${MSGS[ $(test -e "$file";echo $?) ? 321 : 123 ]}"
B: 12 Wrong result, Entry: '/tnt' Broken link
```

### Quick game sample:

Simple ***choose a digit*** game using message array.

```
GAMMSGS=(Exact 'Too small' 'Too big')  target=$((RANDOM%10))  ANSWER=''
while [ "$ANSWER" != "Exact" ]; do
    read -n 1 -p 'Enter a digit: ' play
    ANSWER=${GAMMSGS[ target == play ? 0 : target > play ? 1 : 2 ]}
    echo -e \\nYou try $play: $ANSWER
done
```

sample run:

```
Enter a digit: 0
You try 0: Too small
Enter a digit: 9
You try 9: Too big
Enter a digit: 5
You try 5: Too big
Enter a digit: 3
You try 3: Exact
```

Comment: You can replace `$(test -e "$file";echo $?)` with `$([ -e "$file" ];echo $?)`

Comment: @LéaGris Yes: `help \[` show *This is a synonym for the "test" builtin,*... I juest prefer this syntax in this specific case... Not really more readable, but something so...